# Do something if ? wrong in url

Tags: php

I have a login screen. When you type a wrong password/username, you'll be redirected to the same page, but I want to show an error, so I redirect to index.php?wrong.

Now I want to check:

```
If ?wrong  {
echo "wrong pw"; 
} else {
// nothing
}
```

I'd like to know how to make this. What do I have to write instead of

```
if ?wrong
```

I checked some pages about it, for example [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp), but its about index.php?something=wrong, but I'd like to have just ?wrong.

Thanks a lot!
Art

Comment: try if(isset($_GET['wrong']))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['wrong'])) {
    // wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
if(isset($_GET['wrong']))
{
    //Play
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is the global default PHP 'array', which contains all the url parameters. So use this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['wrong'])) {
  // do stuff
}
?>
```

`isset` checks if `$_GET['wrong']` is valid, in other words, there is `wrong` as a parameter somewhere in the url, so what you were asking for (`?wrong` or `?foo&wrong`) will both be detected.